# Why is my .format() method returning a KeyError in this JSON uri?

Tags: python, string

```
ticker = '$SPY'
f = urlopen("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?q={ticker}&subreddit=wallstreetbets&metadata=true&size=0&after=1610928000&before=1613088000".format(ticker))
j = json.load(f)
j['metadata']['total_results']
```

`KeyError: 'ticker'`

I'm not too sure why this is happening, I believe I have used the .format() approach correctly. The aim is to eventually loop over a list of tickers.

Comment: ``format(ticker=ticker)``... or better yet, use an f-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass it as *keyword* argument.

```
f = urlopen("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?q={ticker}&subreddit=wallstreetbets&metadata=true&size=0&after=1610928000&before=1613088000".format(ticker=ticker))
```

Quoting [from the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101)

> The built-in string class (and also the unicode class in 2.6) will
> gain a new method, 'format', which takes an arbitrary number of
> positional and keyword arguments:
>
> ```
>  "The story of {0}, {1}, and {c}".format(a, b, c=d)
> ```
>
> Within a format
> string, each positional argument is identified with a number, starting
> from zero, so in the above example, 'a' is argument 0 and 'b' is
> argument 1.  **Each keyword argument is identified by its keyword name,
> so in the above example, 'c' is used to refer to the third argument.**